# My NextJs useState Totally stopped working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, next.js13

```
'use client'

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
export default function Home() {
  const [count,setCount] = useState<number>(0)
  const add = ()=>{
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
  }
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={add}>+</button>
    </main>
  )
}
```

This is a simple counter app, but the count is not being updated... This is what my package.json looks like:

```json
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "18",
    "next": "13.5.4",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^",
    "@types/react-dom": "^20",
    "autoprefixer": "^10",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.5.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Any errors either in the browser console or the shell from the server output?

Comment: Hi, no error whatsoever, I am so confused, i am an old user , but trying to migrate to 13 version.

Comment: Yeah I can understand why, AFAICT your code should be fine as written in next 13.

Comment: Maybe do a sanity check, delete any cached files, and rebuild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try to upgrade your Node version, I have had this problem before and after I upgraded Node to `v18.17.1` it worked as expected.

You can check your Node version using this command `node --version` in the terminal.

I found this [reference](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/54328) and think it might help you to go.

Comment: Hi , It is working now , thank you so much for your help